# FactoryBot presenting unexpected behaviour when testing an instance variable assignment in a controller action with rSpec in a Rails 7 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing controller tests with Rspec in a Rails 7 application and getting some unexpected behaviour when asserting against an assignment.

The controller action that I'm testing returns the instance variable `@prefectures`;

```
  def edit
    @prefectures = Prefecture.all.order(:code)
    @city = City.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :edit, locals: { city: @city } }
    end
  end
```

In the tests I'm using FactoryBot to create a list of three `Prefectures` and then checking in the example that the assigned `@prefectures` matches those three.

```
RSpec.describe 'Cities', type: :request do
  let(:city) { create(:city) }
  let(:prefecture_list) { create_list(:prefecture, 3) }

  describe 'GET /edit' do
    it 'succeeds' do
      get edit_city_path(city)
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'assigns @prefectures' do
      expected = prefecture_list.sort_by { |prefecture| prefecture.code }
      get edit_city_path(city)
      expect(assigns(:prefectures)).to eq(expected)
    end
  end
end
```

There are several actions on the controller that return an instance variable of `@prefectures`. There are also a number of tests in the test file that assert the assignment of `@prefectures` using the same FactoryBot list. In each instance FactoryBot instantiates a collection of three prefectures and the test confirms that the assigned '@prefectures' is that same collection of three `Prefectures`.

In the `'GET /edit'` tests, however, the test fails because for reasons I don't understand, the assigned `@prefectures` is a collection of 6 `Prefectures` rather than 3. Each time it runs it's a distinct collection of six so it's not as if three are somehow being saved between test runs and added to. It seems as though in this test instance FactoryBot is creating a list of 6 rather than three.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: The described behaviour suggests that something in the outer context creates another list of 3 prefectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
In the test setup I also create a `city_list`;

```
let(:city_list) { create_list(:city, 3) }
let(:prefecture_list) { create_list(:prefecture, 3) }
```

The `Prefecture` factory creates a `Prefecture`;

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :prefecture do
    name { Faker::Address.state }
    code { Faker::Number.number(digits: 3) }
  end
end
```

The `City` factory creates a `City` with a `Prefecture` because there is a one-to-many relationship between the two;

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :city do
    prefecture { create(:prefecture) }
    name { Faker::Address.city }
    rating { Faker::Number.within(range: 0.0..5.0) }
  end
end
```

The test that is failing is unique among the tests that assert the `@prefectures` assignment as it is the only one that also uses `city_list`. `city_list` appears to create an additional set of three 'Prefectures`.

I fixed the issue by overriding the `prefecture_id` constraint of the `city_list` to use one of the existing prefectures rather that generate it's own new one and the test now passes.

```
let(:prefecture_list) { create_list(:prefecture, 3) }
let(:city_list) { create_list(:city, 3, prefecture_id:prefecture_list[0].id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

##### You need to clean the database after each suite

[Gem database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)

- Example config:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: If he didn't have this at all, he'd have this problem with all other specs, I think.

Comment: yes, I think so. He has 2 `it` blocks. `create_list(:prefecture, 3)` will run 2 times. => 6 records. That is the issue.

Comment: The `it "succeeds"` is not using the list and it's a `let`, not `let!`, so no prefectures will be created in that test.

Comment: you are right. not in this file. maybe still need to clean the database, I think

Comment: Thankyou for the advice, guys. I have experimented with isolating the test: running only this one test file and commenting out all other tests on the file and the issue still, bizarrely, occurs on this one test. I'm going to try `DatabaseCleaner`; should that config go in `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: You should config in `spec_helper.rb`